# Quick Excel Formula - Reorder Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

**I require a reorder formula without adding any extra cells on the sheet (≠helpers).**

I'd like to reorder the 10 vertical cells located in AV63-72 currently in numerical order (2.94-3.35) = SOURCE, in the 10-cells selected array just below (=RESULTs displayed as it should be), according to the positions & values in the 10-cell array just left of the selected=INSTRUCTIONS column.

The vertical positions in all three arrays correspond vertically as static 1-10, but the values for the positions in the INSTRUCTION change as the sheet expands.

So, the instructions for the "2.94" in AV63 being in the 1st position (1.10) would be to write in turn in the 5th position in the RESULT array, where the formulas would be.

Can this be done just leveraging on the data shown, without adding any extra helper arrays on the sheet?

Comment: Maybe it's me, but i find your question kind of messy. Still: are you just asking to rearrange the list of value according to a know order? Have you considered the `INDEX` function?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Yes, but how to account for static positions 1-10 .. without actually adding another column to specify that?

Comment: If I put in AV73 =INDEX(SOURCE,AV73 value), then the result written would be 3.23 as the 5th position in the SOURCE ....

Comment: when it actually needs be taking thre 1st position in SOURCE (since its in the 1st position in INSTRUCTION as well) , so figure 2.94 ..

Comment: & writing it in the 5th position in the RESULT, so the cell AV77!

Comment: The bottom line, the formula in AV77, which is what the original question is, should identify the "5" as the relevant to its 5th position/10th in the RESULT array AV73-AV82 is, then since 5 is in the 1st position/10 th in the INSTRUCTION array -- & thereof find the 1st position in the SOURCE array (2.94) & write it.

Comment: I don't know how to explain any differently .. gotta merge this two point of view into a formula, without adding anything extra on the sheet. @EvilBlueMonkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV73)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0))
```

**FORMULA EVOLUTION**

**1) Mission statement**

REORDER THE LIST

**2) Breaking up the mission statement**

=INDEX(THE DATA LIST, THE INDEX FOR THE GIVEN ROW)

**3) Specifying THE DATA LIST**

=INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72, THE INDEX FOR THE GIVEN ROW)

**4) Breaking up THE INDEX FOR THE GIVEN ROW**

=INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(THE RELATIVE ROW NUMBER, THE INSTRUCTION LIST, PRECISE RESULT))

**5) Specifying PRECISE RESULT**

=INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(THE RELATIVE ROW NUMBER, THE INSTRUCTION LIST,0))

**6) Specifying THE INSTRUCTION LIST**

=INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(THE RELATIVE ROW NUMBER,$AU$73:$AU$82,0))

**7) Breaking up THE RELATIVE ROW NUMBER**

=INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH( THIS ROW NUMBER - THE FIRST ROW OF THE RESULT LIST + 1 ,$AU$73:$AU$82,0))

**8) Specifying THE FIRST ROW OF THE RESULT LIST**

=INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH( THIS ROW NUMBER - ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0))

**9) Specifying THIS ROW NUMBER**

=INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV73)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0))

**FORMULA EXPLODED**

```
=INDEX(                          Pick from
      $AV$63:$AV$72,             the data list
      MATCH(                     the element with index equal to the row whose value is equal
            ROW(                 to the row
                AV73             of this row
               )
            -                    minus
            ROW(                 the row
                $AV$73           of the initial row of the result list
               )
            +1,                  plus one
            $AU$73:$AU$82,       among the instruction list
            0                    with precision
           )
      )
```

**FORMULA NOTED**

```
=INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV73)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0))
|  A  |      B      |  C  |    D    |    E     | F|      G      |H|
```

We need to search the list of instruction (part G) for each number from 1 to 10. We use a match function (part C) to search the list of instruction (part G) with precision (part H). Our results will be listed in a column, therefore each result will be stored in a row of said column. Since we need the series of number from 1 to 10, we take the row number for the given cell (part D) minus the row number for the starting cell of the results list (part E) plus 1 (part F). Note the relative reference of the given cell (part D) and the absolute reference of the starting cell of the results list (part E); said references will allow us to [drag](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-excel-for-mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218) the cell down to easily change the relative references while keeping the absolute one. This will return us a 1 for the first cell of the result list, a 2 for the second cell of the result list, a 3 for the third cell... and so on. Thanks to this, our match function (part C) will find at what row of the instruction list is stored the number equal to the given row of the result list. We can use this result to search the data list (part B) using a index function (part A).

The whole list of results will ultimately have these formulas:

|  |
| --- |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV73)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV74)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV75)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV76)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV77)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV78)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV79)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV80)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV81)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |
| =INDEX($AV$63:$AV$72,MATCH(ROW(AV82)-ROW($AV$73)+1,$AU$73:$AU$82,0)) |

Comment: Irregardless of where I paste the above formula, even completely irrelevant cells, I always get the same static result of '3.00'.

Comment: Something, some value has to become floating .. some $ removed, at least. That's my intution, based on my so-far excel knowledge. I have no idea how, but might you attempt again?

Comment: Ah ye, sorry. I should have foreseen this. You have to paste it in cell AV73 and then [drag](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-excel-for-mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218) it down to cover AV73:AV82. Or you can paste it in cell AV73 then copy it to the rest of the range. It's the same. Anyway it's "regardless", not "irregardless".

Comment: Works for the field AV73 correctly, but does not scale for the next 9 vells vertically below till AV82.

Comment: Did you paste it and then [drag](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-excel-for-mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218) it down?

Comment: Might you explain the structure of the formula, whateverything does .. from the top level, I guess according to INDEX .. & then how other formulas fit within it & what those do.